Powershell task in task scheduler fails to launch
I have a powershell script that runs fine by itself, or when run from the CMD window, but "fails to launch" when run from the task scheduler on this computer. (It runs OK on another computer).
This is the task:
$regPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\KFM"
$regName = "KFMLastDismissTimestamp"
$epochMicroseconds = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s
$epochSeconds = [Math]::Floor($epochMicroseconds)

New-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name $regName -Value $epochSeconds -PropertyType DWORD -Force > $NULL

This is the task schedule item as exported:
<Task xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task" version="1.4">
<RegistrationInfo>
<Date>2024-10-10T07:37:18.4456125</Date>
<Author>RONBP-2\ron</Author>
<Description>Resets KFM LastDismissTime daily to avoid save to OneDrive nag in Office</Description>
<URI>\Reset KFM</URI>
</RegistrationInfo>
<Triggers>
<CalendarTrigger>
<StartBoundary>2024-10-10T04:00:00</StartBoundary>
<Enabled>true</Enabled>
<ScheduleByDay>
<DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
</ScheduleByDay>
</CalendarTrigger>
<BootTrigger>
<Enabled>true</Enabled>
</BootTrigger>
</Triggers>
<Principals>
<Principal id="Author">
<UserId>S-1-5-21-454476332-2067298727-2451185795-1001</UserId>
<LogonType>Password</LogonType>
<RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
</Principal>
</Principals>
<Settings>
<MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
<DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
<StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
<AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
<StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
<RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
<IdleSettings>
<StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
<RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
</IdleSettings>
<AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
<Enabled>true</Enabled>
<Hidden>false</Hidden>
<RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
<DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
<UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
<WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
<ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
<Priority>7</Priority>
</Settings>
<Actions Context="Author">
<Exec>
<Command>"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe"</Command>
<Arguments>-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "C:\PowerShell Scripts\KFMReset.ps1"</Arguments>
</Exec>
</Actions>
</Task>

The settings on the other computer are almost identical, except for the absence of the -ExecutionPolicy argument. On both computers the policy was set to RemoteSigned and I have tried on this computer with and without specifically setting the policy in the task scheduler script.
The Task Scheduler history with the current script shows failure to launch.
Thank you.

See if running it as SYSTEM as <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId> or using https://imgur.com/yX3aE9n and typing in SYSTEM allows it to run as expected once it runs under system security context. Ping me back and let me know if it works, and I'll be happy to post an answer.

Furthermore, I have seen when you have your scripts in a "trusted" site zone assignment HKLM wise as the local machine "trusted" path, this can workaround security as long as the script is located in the trusted site location such as a UNC path. i.e. \\server.domain.com\Share\PSScript. This may be worth a shot too but depends on how tight you're locked down, other security software and configurations, etc. These are just two quick ideas.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Running as SYSTEM didn't work. But I changed it back to <UserId>S-1-5-21-454476332-2067298727-2451185795-1001</UserId> and now it seems to be running. I made no other changes.

¯⁠\⁠_⁠ʘ⁠‿⁠ʘ⁠_⁠/⁠¯

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle It stopped working. However, the problem may be elsewhere. Although the script runs if I double-click on the file in File Explorer, it does not run from the Powershell instance. In other words, if I open Powershell (with admin privileges) and enter "C:\PowerShell Scripts\KFMReset.ps1" it does not execute. I need to investigate further and possibly post a new question.
